# Trouble setting WS response schema

Tags: java, web-services, spring-ws, castor

I'm using soapUI to test some WebServices.

In MockService available in soapUI I get this default response

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sch="http://www.someurl.com/schemas">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
             <sch:Response>
                 <sch:Something>?</sch:Something>
             </sch:Response>
        </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
```

When the real Webservice is called I don't get xmlns:sch="http://www.someurl.com/schemas" and the elements inside the response doesn't come with 'sch' prefix. Here is what I get:

```
       <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
                 <Response>
                     <Something>something</Something>
                 </Response>
            </soapenv:Body>
       </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm using Java with spring-ws. And using Castor to marshall xml to Java Object.

How to include the schema in the response?

**EDIT**: Adding configuration details.

myApplication-servlet.xml is like this

```
<bean id="payloadMapping"
        class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping">
        <property name="endpointMap">
            <map>
                <entry
                    key="{http://www.someurl.com/schemas}MyRequest"
                    value-ref="myEndpoint"/>                
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="myEndpoint"
        class="foo.bar.myEndpoint">
        <constructor-arg ref="messageSource" />
        <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    </bean>

<bean id="myWsdlDefinition"
        class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition">
        <property name="schema">
            <bean class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
                <property name="xsd" value="/MyXsd.xsd" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="portTypeName" value="myPortTypeName" />
        <property name="locationUri" value="http://anotherUrl:8080/services" />
    </bean>

<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller">
        <property name="mappingLocation" value="classpath:mapping.xml" />
    </bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="errors" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: We can't tell you why Spring-WS has been mis-configured if you give us no information on your setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mapping file I have to put ns-prefix in the map-to element.

```
<map-to xml="Response" ns-prefix="sch" />
```

Comment: Can you post how your config file looks now, pls?